# useEffect not applying classNames

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm currently working on a project using Next JS, where I seem to have encountered an issue with React. Here is the simplified version of my code. I did try to replicate the issue in codesandbox but I couldn't. I'll keep trying though and if I can, I'll update this post with the link.

```
const Nav = React.forwardRef<
  HTMLDivElement,
  { className?: string; disableAnimation?: boolean }
>((props, ref) => {


  const navWrapperRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
  const navItemsRef = useRef<HTMLSpanElement[]>([]);



  useEffect(() => {
    const path = window.location.pathname;
    if (path === "/") navItemsRef.current[0].classList.add("nav-active");
    else if (path.includes("/packages"))
      navItemsRef.current[1].classList.add("nav-active");
    else if (path.includes("/bhutan"))
      navItemsRef.current[2].classList.add("nav-active");
  }, []);

  return (
    <nav className={props.className || "nav"} ref={navWrapperRef}>
      <div className="nav-container">
        <ul className="nav-ul">
          {navLinks.map((link) => (
            <button
              key={uniqueId(`nav-links-${new Date().getUTCDate()}`)}
              data-name={link.name}
              className="nav-links"
            >
              <span
                ref={(el) => navItemsRef.current.push(el as HTMLSpanElement)}
                className="nav-span"
              >
                <Link href={link.href}>{link.name}</Link>
              </span>
            </button>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  );
});
```

My objective here is to implement a navigation component without the use of states. I'd like to render out the current active navigation link on the initial page load using the empty dependency array as for the useEffect hook. But I can't seem to get it to work.

My desired output is the following on page load:

[image: My desired output]

The output I get:

[image: Output I get]

However, if I remove the dependency array altogether then all seems to work fine as expected. But if I am not wrong I think this causes performance issues as it re-renders each and every time if there are any other state changes. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The contents of your [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) hook will run once on mount and whenever its dependencies change.

As this is reliant on what you have defined as `path`, I'd move it out of the [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) and add it as a dependency.

**Update**: you will have to use [`next/router`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router)'s [`useRouter`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router#router-object) hook instead of the window directly when working with [next](https://nextjs.org/).

Demo [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/interesting-moon-7lco0).

```js
const { asPath } = useRouter();

useEffect(() => {
  if (asPath === "/") navItemsRef.current[0].classList.add("nav-active");
  else if (asPath.includes("/packages"))
    navItemsRef.current[1].classList.add("nav-active");
  else if (asPath.includes("/bhutan"))
    navItemsRef.current[2].classList.add("nav-active");
}, [asPath]);
```

Comment: Well I tried as you said, but sadly it didn't work :(. I get an error saying `window is not defined`. Basically window object is undefined.

Comment: I'll try reproducing this in a sandbox and report back.

Comment: Aight, I'll try too

Comment: Where are you getting your `<Link />` component from? `react-router-dom`, `next`? I'm wondering if we have to use their routers.

Comment: I'm using next js for the `<Link />` component

Comment: I have a working demo [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/interesting-moon-7lco0) and have updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Let me try it and get back to you

Comment: Ummm... It's still not working. Want to help me out thru discord? Add me Danzy#4588